# How to eliminate all odd lines from a file but preserve line 1 with a single liner?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a series of files with the following structure

```
Header1
Data2
Garbage3
Data4
Garbage5
Data6
```

I want to preserve the header(line1) and data(even lines), and throw away the garbage(odd lines except 1). I came about with an ugly solution:

```
echo $(head -n 1 file.txt) $(awk 'NR%2==0' file.txt) | tr " " "\n" > file.tmp #I cannot rewrite file.txt directly
mv file.tmp file.txt
```

Is there a way to elegantly do this in a single line?. Note: I don't want to print to the STDOUT, I want to replace file.txt for a clean version of itself?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR%2==0||NR==1' odd
Header1
Data2
Data4
Data6
```

This will print lines based on two conditions:

1. Line number 1 is printed.  OR
2. Any line which is divisible by 2 is printed.

To make changes in the file:

```
awk 'NR%2==0||NR==1' odd >odd.tmp && mv odd.tmp odd
```

Comment: I want to replace odd for a clean version of itself. Your solution oly prints to the screen. awk 'NR%2==0||NR==1' odd > odd leaves an empty odd file

Comment: @j91 try `awk 'NR%2==0||NR==1' odd >odd.tmp && mv odd.tmp odd`

Answer (score 1):

Use below command, it will do in-file itself.

```
sed -ie '1p;1~2d' filename.txt
```

Example:

```
$ cat sample.txt
Header1
Data2
Garbage3
Data4
Garbage5
Data6
$
$ sed -ie '1p;1~2d' sample.txt
$
$
$ cat sample.txt
Header1
Data2
Data4
Data6
$
```

Answer (score 0):

the sed (gnu sed) one-liners should work:

```
sed -n '1{p;n};p;n' file
```

OR

```
sed -n '1p;0~2p' file
```

with your example, both output:

```
Header1
Data2
Data4
Data6
```